# Bootstrap 4 beta not working react babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap 4 to display an error of an input from a form.
Everything It's working but once I click the "SignUp" button with the empty form, no red error is display it. So the ""has-danger"" class from Bootstrap 4 doesn't work. I would like to know if the is any other way to user the *error* class from Bootstap 4.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      email: '',
      errors: {},
      isLoading: false
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({errors: {}, isLoading: true});
    this.props.userSignUpRequest(this.state).then(() => {}, ({data}) => this.setState({errors: data, isLoading: false}));

  }
  render() {
    const {errors} = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className={classnames('form-group', {'has-danger': errors.firstname})}>
          <label className="form-control-label">
            First Name
          </label>
          <input value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" name="firstname" className="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1"/> {errors.firstname && <span className="help-block">{errors.firstname}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group has-danger">
          <label className="form-control-label">
            Last Name
          </label>
          <input value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" name="lastname" className="form-control form-control-danger"/> {errors.lastname && <span className="help-block">{errors.lastname}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="control-label">
            Username
          </label>
          <input value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" name="username" className="form-control"/> {errors.username && <span className="help-block">{errors.username}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="control-label">
            Password
          </label>
          <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" name="password" className="form-control"/> {errors.password && <span className="help-block">{errors.password}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="control-label">
            Email
          </label>
          <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" name="email" className="form-control"/> {errors.email && <span className="help-block">{errors.email}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="text-left">
          <small>By clicking Submit, I agree that I have read and accepted the
            <a href="#"> Terms and conditions</a>
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group mt-1">
          <button disabled={this.state.isLoading} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

SignUpForm.propTypes = {
  userSignUpRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

Comment: Where is the relevant import of bootstrap-4?

Comment: @Dekel I added the cdn link to bootstrap on the index.html file

Comment: When you say "everything's working except blah blah" do you mean all other Bootstrap 4 stuff is working? Or all the site is working EXCEPT Bootstrap 4 stuff. Also have you inspected the element in the webpage? Is the class actually getting added to the input when you try to submit with an empty form? If so does that class have the CSS properties you thought? And are those properties maybe getting overridden by some CSS from some other file?

Comment: Where in the code did you add the `has-error` class?

Comment: @Dekel has-danger, sorry

Comment: @Jayce444 yes, the rest classes from bootstrap are working perfectly. It's just this """has-danger""" class